# Changing image on click of text

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm having some problems getting a different image to display on click of some text. I have a red button which on click of the text should change to a green button, but the way I have it set up it doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated. Below is my code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".note").click(function(){    
    // get the search values
    var id = $(this).attr('id')
    var id_array = id.split('_')
    var note_num = id_array[1]

    if($(this).hasClass('hide'))
    {
        $(this).removeClass('hide').addClass('show')
        $("#note_details_"+note_num).slideDown()

        if($(this).hasClass('new_note')){
            $(this).removeClass('new_note')
            $("#note_indicator_"+note_num).this.src='images/buttons/green_icon.png';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).removeClass('show').addClass('hide')
        $("#note_details_"+note_num).slideUp()
    }

})

 });
</script>
```

This is in my page

```
<?
    if(!empty($notes)):
        foreach($notes as $note):
    ?>
    <div id="hdr_active">
     <input type="checkbox"/></label>
     <div style='display:inline-block;' id='note_<?=$note->note_id?>' class="note new_note hide"><span id='note_indicator_<?=$note->note_id?>'><img src="images/buttons/red_icon.png" class="note_indicator" width="6" height="6" /></span><?=$note->title?></div>
     <div id='note_details_<?=$note->note_id?>' class="details" style="display: none">
     <p><?=$note->details?></p>
     </div>
    </div>
    <?
        endforeach;
    endif;
    ?>
```

Comment: if you make a fiddle then it will be easy to helpout

Comment: this is not an answer to your question.."id" should never repeat. In you code <div id="hdr_active"> is repeating..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
<div style='display:inline-block;' id='note_<?=$note->note_id?>' class="note new_note hide"><span id='note_indicator_<?=$note->note_id?>'><img src="images/buttons/red_icon.png" class="note_indicator" width="6" height="6" /></span><?=$note->title?></div>
```

by:

```
    <div style='display:inline-block;' id='note_<?=$note->note_id?>' class="note new_note hide"><img src="images/buttons/red_icon.png" id='note_indicator_<?=$note->note_id?>' width="6" height="6" /
   <?=$note->title?>
   </div>
```

then replace in your jquery:

```
$("#note_indicator_"+note_num).this.src='images/buttons/green_icon.png';
```

by:

```
$(".note_indicator").attr("src","images/buttons/green_icon.png");
```

I think this is what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks guys for your help. I've tried that Ryokel but it's not working. I've created a fiddle although the javascript doesn't work, but i basically need the red button to display green when you click on the "Hello World text".

http://jsfiddle.net/RLJFL/1/

Comment: you use # for a class but you must use . for a class i will edit my code. Edit: try the edited codeit should work.

Comment: Thanks Ryokel, that works. The only thing is that I have 5 titles. I only want it to change to green when I click on the specific title, but at the moment it changes all 5 titles to green instead of just the one i've clicked on

Comment: Here you change the class note_indicator. To change only one title put id to your images ( I think you can delete the span and use their id to the images) and then use this to change images : $("#note_indicator_"+note_num).attr("src","images/buttons/green_icon.png");

Comment: I edited my answerto help and this should work as you expected

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code, you are mistaking ids, also the split element you need is the second.
    jsfiddle.net/RLJFL/4/

I can't make a comment but your solutions wont work. Because this code

```
var id_array = id.split('_')
var note_num = id_array[1]
```

id_array[1] - will get indecator, you must change it to id_array[2] in order to get the proper note_num

Comment: I have indicated where the errors are, so what do you need more? The first mistake is the note_num parameter to be id_array[2] and the second is stated by Ryokel in hist answear